# Traversing td/tr with jquery's closest()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, closest

```
<td width="162"><span class="required">*</span> Name:</td>
<td width="407">
    <label>
        <input id="store_name" class="text_field alnum" type="text" minlength="3"
        maxlength="30" size="40" name="store_name" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"/>
    </label>
</td>
<td class="char_count_area" style="color: green;"/>
```

I have some jQuery code that goes like this:

```
$('.text_field').each(function(){
        $(this).keyup(function(){                 
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.char_count_area').html(remainingChars); 
....
```

As you can see, I'm trying to reach `char_count_area` from `text_field` in a rather inefficient manner.
It works, but it goes crazy if I alter the table design slightly.
I've tried using

```
$(this).closest('.char_count_area').html(remainingChars)
```

but it doesn't work (characters don't appear).

How can I achieve this using `closest` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've tidied your code somewhat (removed the `each()` as it's not needed and better qualified your selector. Using just CSS classes is not best practice, specifying an element name too will be more performant).

```
$('input.text_field').keyup(function(){                                 
    $(this).closest('td').next().html(remainingChars);
});
```

bear in mind that [`closest()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest) was added in jQuery 1.3, so if you're using an older version of jQuery then you might want to use

```
$('input.text_field').keyup(function(){                                 
    $(this).parent().parent().next().html(remainingChars);
});
```

This will be fine, so long as the `<input>` remains in an element in a `<td>`, and the next `<td>` is the one with CSS class `char_count_area`

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment, here's a better solution that relies less on DOM positions

```
('input.text_field').keyup(function(){                                 
    $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td.char_count_area').html(remainingChars);
});
```

Comment: ok thanks. one issue - occasionally i have another <td> BEFORE char_count_area, so next(); never reaches char_count_area, i'd have to use next().next().. I'm hoping to use the same javascript code universally. This is why I was trying to specifically designate the closest '.char_count_area', rather then any 'td'. Any help?